# Getting PNG map from PostGIS to Node and then jquery

Tags: jquery, node-js, postgis-2.2

Using Jquery, I am aiming to get png map from postGIS which has been created dynamically from node server in different port. I used jsonp to overcome cross domain issue in jquery.

$.ajax( 'http://localhost:3000/terrain', {
              type:'GET',
                  crossOrigin: true,
                  data:koordObj,
                  contentType: "content-Type: application/image",
                  dataType: "jsonp",
                  success:function (data) {
                  console.log(data);
              }
            })
        .error( function() {
            console.log("error");
        });

server creates the image as :
"
localhost:3000/terrain/?callback=photos&minx=4000660.554526325&miny=4862598.159515699&maxx=4014342.782589372&maxy=4869286.399490653&terrain=slp&zoom=14&_=1459928691680
 "

But firefox arises this error:
SyntaxError: illegal character
�PNG
​What might the problem be?